# How to solve KeyError in python?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, keyerror, pre-trained-model, fine-tuning

I am fine tuning a HG model on my own data. I get this error which I can not find the solution.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/neg97727/ownCloud/Negin_Master_Thesis/thesis/scripts/scripts/venv1/test4.py", line 268, in <module>
    trainer.train()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\transformers\trainer.py", line 1254, in train
    for step, inputs in enumerate(epoch_iterator):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 634, in next
    data = self._next_data()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\dataloader.py", line 678, in _next_data
    data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 51, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\utils\data\_utils\fetch.py", line 51, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
KeyError: 2
```

I have tried checking the length of `train_labels, val_labels, and test_labels` matches the length of `train_texts, val_texts, and test_texts`.

Also specify different file_path for train_dataset and test_dataset. But still the same error. I am beginner and can not find out where can I check and how to find a solution.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please do format your question so that we can understand/read the error easily. Also, please (i) add the code that caused the error, (ii) state which transformers version you are using `import transformers; transformers.__version__` , (iii) which model from huggingface are you trying to use? (iv) for which task? and (v) what dataset. Then it'll be easier to help others help you.